# Track changes brought by syncing with iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I am trying to implement iCloud and I would need to notify the user about how does syncing with iCloud change the data. For example such notification would include that one more object has been added to the UITableView and can now be viewed.

Thanks

Comment: iCloud notifies your app when changes happen, you can then notify the user if you want. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I know when the update happens, but I wanted to be able to track exactly what the changes are brought by iCloud. I want to know what are those changes in order to display them to the user.

Comment: Which iCloud API(s) are you using? There's more than one, and the answer would depend on the one you're using. Core Data, documents, key-value store? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iCloud posts `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`, you know that changes have been received from the cloud. The `userInfo` dictionary on this notification tells you what objects have changed. Look for values for the `NSInsertedObjectsKey`, `NSUpdatedObjectsKey`, and `NSDeletedObjectsKey` keys. The values for those keys will list managed object IDs that identify the affected objects.

You don't get any notification of what attributes have changed on updated objects. If you have already loaded them, you could compare your loaded values with the new ones. Get the new values using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `existingObjectWithID:error:` method, and compare the resulting object to the one you already have. Do this *before* calling `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`, so that you can still access the pre-merge state. If you don't already have it loaded, you can't get the attribute changes, because loading the object will show only the new values.